# Disable hover for different screen size

Tags: html, css

I have 7 images and those 7 images will be zoomed when mouse over on it. This style I want to apply for only desktop version.

Unfortunately, when I use `@media screen` for other platforms, it still work which make unresponsive page on other platforms.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="first container text-center" id="background">
</div>
<div class="second container text-center" id="background">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.first-body {
  background: url(../../images/MANGO_copy.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
  top: 250px;
  z-index: 10016;
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
first-body:hover {
  height: 400px;
  background-size: 800px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  opacity: .9;
  -webkit-opacity: .9;
  -moz-opacity: .9;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle.

Comment: @Kamal Sorry no demo, but u can access to see more detail [link](http://kite-ds.com/web_clients/sovereign/retail.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can apply this hover css above 980px in media

```
@media (min-width: 980px) {

    first-body:hover{
    height:400px; 
    background-size:800px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.1,1.1);
    }
}
```

or override the hover effect in media

```
@media (max-width: 980px) {
    first-body:hover{
       height:400px; 
       background-size:800px;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
      -moz-transform:scale(1,1);
      opacity:.9;
      -webkit-opacity: .9;
      -moz-opacity: .9;
      transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Could you explain more?

Comment: Apply  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
      -moz-transform:scale(1.1,1.1);  on desktop view and override the same property in media query below 980 with  -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
      -moz-transform:scale(1,1); It will not get zoomed.

Answer (score 0):

With media queries you can target the :hover style to certain screen size:

*(Try full screen snippet and resize your browser)*

```css
#background,
#background-third {
  width: 760px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.first-body {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/g/800/400/) no-repeat;
  background-size: 820px;
  background-position: top center;
  top: 250px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
#mango-logo {
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  right: 23%;
  position: absolute;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .first-body:hover {
    height: 400px;
    background-size: 800px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    opacity: .9;
    -webkit-opacity: .9;
    -moz-opacity: .9;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="StyleSheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="first-body container text-center" id="background">
  <div class="col-lg-8 pull-right">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/200/40/" id="mango-logo" class="brand" style="margin-top:30%;">
    <div class="info" id="mango">
      <p>In 2011, MANGO flagship store appear in the heart of Phnom Penh's central business district and is the first global brand open in the Kingdom of Cambodia. MANGO is a transnational Spanish clothing based in Barcelona that specializes in fashion for
        young urban women. The brand is well-known as one of the most famous and popular high clothing.</p>
      <div id="info" class="button">visit website</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```